# Exclude sticky post from main query?

Tags: sticky-post

I am having alot of trouble with this. I was using `<?php query_posts( array( 'post__not_in' => get_option( 'sticky_posts' ), 'paged' => get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) ); ?>` to exclude the posts from the main query on the my homepage because stickies are being used in the slider. I am making this theme for wordpress.org and I was told that was not recommended. I then tried adding this to my functions.php but to no avail:

```
/**
 * Excluding sticky posts from home page. Sticky posts are in a slider.
 *
 * @since 0.1
 */
function essential_exclude_sticky( $query ) {

    /* Exclude if is home and is main query. */
    if ( is_home() && $query->is_main_query() )
        $query->set( 'ignore_sticky_posts', true );

}
```

`

Any idea on what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 5):

`query_posts` isn't recommended because its [breaks things](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts#Caveats).

You're really close, but just declaring the function itself will not work.  You need to [hook](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API) the function into something.  In your case, this would be `pre_get_posts`.

Example (with "namespaced" function):

```
<?php
// this is key!
add_action('pre_get_posts', 'wpse74620_ignore_sticky');
// the function that does the work
function wpse74620_ignore_sticky($query)
{
    // sure we're were we want to be.
    if (is_home() && $query->is_main_query())
        $query->set('ignore_sticky_posts', true);
}
```

Comment: Works like a charm. Thank you for explaining it, I need to learn these things! ;p

Comment: @Steven Click the [check mark](http://i.stack.imgur.com/G1SEk.png) to mark this answer as The Solution.

Answer (score 4):

For me, using `ignore_sticky_posts` keeps sticky posts from showing at the top, but they still show in chronological order with the other posts.

I'm using `post__not_in` with `get_option('sticky_posts')` to exclude sticky posts from the main query.

```
<?php
/**
 * Exclude sticky posts from home page.
 */
function theme_name_ignore_sticky_posts($query){
  if (is_home() && $query->is_main_query())
    $query->set('post__not_in', get_option('sticky_posts'));
}
add_action('pre_get_posts', 'theme_name_ignore_sticky_posts');
?>
```

Comment: This is the correct answer. ignore_sticky_posts just makes them behave as if they're not sticky, so they'll still show in the main query.  To totally exclude them, this method is the correct approach.